# Animating color change in Velocity.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-animate, velocity.js

I've just started using Velocity.js and am trying to make a simple animation where I change the color of a circle from red to yellow. The HTML I have is just...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg height=300 width=300>
    <circle id="example" cx=50 cy=50 r=20 fill="red"></circle>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

...and I am trying to change the color of the circle to yellow in my JavaScript like this:

```
$('#example')
   .delay(1000)
   .velocity({fill: "yellow"});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the **[velocity.js docs](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#svg)**, you need to pass fill colour value as a hex string:

***Snippet:***

```js
$('#example').delay(1000).velocity({ fill: '#ffff00' }, { duration: 2000 });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<svg height=300 width=300>
    <circle id="example" cx=50 cy=50 r=20 fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. You are trying to load multiple jQuery versions i.e. `1.8.3` and `1.9.1`. Remove the unnecessary one.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish with backgroundColor vs. Fill.

```
  var colorCode = "#D32D27"
    $("#ColorDIV").velocity({ 
          backgroundColor: colorCode,
          opacity: 1
    }, 1000);           

    colorCode = "#FFDD00"
    $("#ColorDIV").velocity({ 
          backgroundColor: colorCode,
          opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please give some explanation, because code-only answers are not of much value to other users.